# html iframe loaded file name & id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am working on a .asp.net web site.

I am loading a page in iframe (say pre-payment page). This page proceeds to another page e.g. payment page, which is a page from external site. On successful payment the sucesspayment.aspx page is loaded (in iframe again) or else failurepayment.aspx is loaded. I want o know thru javascript when succespayment.aspx or failurepayment.aspx is loaded.

Here is my code

```
  <script>
  function pageLoad() {
        var url = window.location.search;
        var frameBaseSRC = "PrePayment.aspx";
        document.getElementById("iframe1").src = frameBaseSRC + url;

        var iframeSrcChangeEvt = new Event("iframeSrcChanged"); 

  document.getElementById("iframe1").addEventListener("iframeSrcChanged", 
  function () { 
            this.src = frameBaseSRC + url;
            this.removeEventListener("iframeSrcChanged"); 
            clearInterval(monitorIframe); 
        });

    }
</script>

<body onload="pageLoad()">

<iframe style="height: 513px; width: 1071px" id="iframe1" sandbox="allow-    
 same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms " ></iframe>
</body>
```

In my case, I am seeing, MutationObserver is not working. I dont know the reason.

How do I know which page is getting loaded, i.e the name of the page getting loaded in iFrame.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: In general not possible, because Same Origin Policy. (Only possible if the remote site actively participates, f.e. by supporting cross-domain communication via postMessage.)

Comment: @CBore, actually succespayment.aspx & failurepayment.aspx are my own site pages. the iframe is in a page within my site too, Only payment page is external.

Comment: Well then you should be able to simply call a function in your parent page from within those pages … probably easier than dealing with event handling across frames.